# How to use a -coin so a TM can decide an undecidable language in polynomial time?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, randomized-algorithms, randomness, chernoff-bound

In "Computational complexity- A modern approach" book (page 117) for the lemma 7.12 (following) the author mentioned that if the ρ is efficiently computable ρ-coin cannot give probabilistic algorithm a new power. Then he  states: "The exercises show that if ρ is not efficiently computable, then a ρ-coin can indeed provide additional power."

Lemma 7.12: A coin with Pr[Heads] = ρ can be simulated by a PTM in expected time O(1) provided the ith bit of ρ is computable in poly(i) time.

The exercise that supposed to show, if ρ is not efficiently computable, then a ρ-coin can indeed provide additional power is the following:

Exercise: Describe a real number ρ such that given a random coin that comes up “Heads” with probability ρ, a Turing machine can decide an undecidable language in polynomial time.

Now, how can we show that if ρ is not efficiently computable, then a ρ-coin can indeed provide an additional power for a probabilistic algorithm to decide some undeniable language in polynomial time?

*I removed the hint because it made me more confused but you can find it at the end of the book.

I strongly believe that this is a research level problem and proper to be discussed in theoretical computer science society because this is a high level question about computational complexity and this question has not been discussed anywhere else.

Comment: Somehow I think I should use Chernoff bound but I don't know how.

Comment: We don’t do homework problems here. Look up Chaitin’s constant.

Comment: Aryeh, I checked Chaitin’s constant it seems it is not efficiently computable but how can it provide an additional power for probabilistic algorithm?

Comment: OK, there's a minor trick -- see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I'll take as given the existence of Chaitin's constant $\Omega\in[0,1]$, and that knowing its first $k$ bits is equivalent to be able to decide the halting problem for all Turning machines of size up to $k$:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant

Given access to an $\Omega$-biased coin, one can use Chernoff bounds to compute $\hat\Omega_k$, which agrees with $\Omega$ up to $k$ bits (i.e., $|\Omega-\hat\Omega_k|<1/2^{k+1}$), by sampling the coin $O(2^{2k})$ times. Now this is exponential in $k$ and is actually tight, so how does this square with the problem statement:
"Describe a real number $\rho$ such that given a random coin that comes up “Heads” with probability $\rho$, a Turing machine can decide **an** undecidable language in *polynomial* time" ?

The trick is to use a very inefficient encoding for the undecidable language.
Fix a universal encoding (the same one used to define $\Omega$) and consider the language $L$, which consists of all Turing machine descriptions $<M>$, such that $M$ halts on all inputs. Clearly, $L$ is undecidable. Now order $L$ in lexicographic order where $<M_i>$ is the $i$th word, and define $L'$ to consist of the words $<M_i'>$, where $M_i'$ is a TM equivalent to $M_i$ (the two halt on and accept the same set of inputs), but $M_i'$ contains an additional $2^i$ dummy states.

Thus, to determine whether a word $x$ belongs to the undecidable language $L'$, one only needs to know $O(\log|x|)$ bits of $\Omega$, which is feasible in expected poly$(|x|)$ time via the argument above.

Comment: Thanks, Aryeh! I still have a little problem understanding it but your logic seems right. I just want to add Chaitin's constant is a real number that is not computable.

Comment: One more question, the book didn't mention Chaitin's constant at all and I didn't heard of that before. It seems without knowing of Chaitin's constant it is impossible to do the prove. Where should I learn this? Can you please introduce a good reference that can be more helpful?

Comment: That's a good pedagogical question. Maybe the author expects you to discover something like $\Omega$ on your own. For background on the latter, you can look here
https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Information-Theory-Telecommunications-Processing/dp/0471241954

Comment: You just need to come up with the idea to encode the HALTING language as an infinite string. I don't think that's unreasonable.

Comment: Indeed— though one does need to make the encoding *of the language* “exponentially inefficient”, I think.

Comment: Sasha, can you please explain more?